# Ef Core 3.1 Getting Customers with optional contacts

Tags: lambda, entity-framework-core

I have a model where a customer can have 0..N contacts.
The contact relation have a ContactType. 'Primary', 'Report Reciever' or 'Not set'.

0 = 'not set'
1 = 'Primary Contact'
2 = 'Report Reciever'

I would like to have:

- All customers, even if the don't have a contact
- only the primary contact if the have one. And if there are two only the first one (if possiable).

This is what I have right now. But of course it will only return customers with a primary contact.

```cs
var customers= ctx.Customers
    .Include(x => x.CustomerContacts)
    .Where(x => x.CustomerContacts.Any(y => y.ContactTypeId == 1))
    .ToList();
```

For now I have created a view with the following sql:

```
select c.ID CustomerId, c.NAME CustomerName, ctype.NAME CustomerType,   ct.NAME ContactName, ct.EMAIL ContactEmail, ct.PHONE ContactPhone from CUSTOMER c
left outer join CUSTOMER_TYPE ctype on c.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = ctype.ID
left outer join CUSTOMER_CONTACT_MAP map on c.id = map.customer_id and map.CONTACT_TYPE_ID = 1
left outer join CUSTOMER_CONTACT ct on ct.ID = map.CONTACT_ID
order by c.NAME;
```

Hint! I think DefaultIfEmpty could be the key to solved the left outer join problem.

I am using the new Oracle provider for ef core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I think your least bad option (besides waiting for filtered includes in EF Core 5) is to query for the customers and the primary contact into separate properties of a wrapping object. Your query could look like this:

```
var results = ctx.Customers
     .Select(c => new {
        Customer = c,
        PrimaryContact = c.CustomerContacts.Where(cc => cc.ContactTypeId == 1).FirstOrDefault()
     }).ToList();
```

You should probably also specify which contact of Type 1 you want to fetch if there's more than one using an OrderBy